# Wrong flex for search items

Tags: html, css, button, input, flexbox

There is a website

[flexfail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFuV3.png)

[buttonalign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKx1G.png)

[inputalign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ9tl.png)

but it is required

[successflex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE3tL.png)

My example code (flexfail)

```css
.crossline, .bottompart {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 33%;*/
}

.crosslineright {
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 40px;*/
    /*margin-left: 20px;*/
    /*margin-right: 20px;*/
    /*align: right;*/
    text-align: right;
}

.close {
        margin-top: -14px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownwindowright {
    width: 75%;
}

.CatalogMenuSearch #SearchBlock {
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid orange;*/
}

#SearchBlock {
    padding-top: 5px;
    /*padding-left: 25px;*/
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    /*padding-right: 50px;*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;  
    height: 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#SearchInputdiv {
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(100%-35px);
    flex: 1;
}

#SearchButtondiv {
    height: 100%;
    /*justify-content: flex-end;*/
    flex: 35px;
}

#SearchButton button svg{
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*justify-content: flex-end;
    flex: 35px;*/
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindowright">
                    <div class="crosslineright">
                        <div class="close">&times;</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
                        <div id="SearchBlock">
                            <div id="SearchInputdiv">
                                <input type="search" placeholder="Search goods" id="SearchInput">
                            </div>
                            <div id="SearchButtondiv">
                                <button id="SearchButton"><svg class=" Icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.22703 5.22703C7.86307 2.591 12.1369 2.591 14.773 5.22703C17.2298 7.68382 17.3968 11.5632 15.2742 14.2135L19.0607 18L18 19.0607L14.2135 15.2742C11.5632 17.3968 7.68381 17.2298 5.22703 14.773C2.59099 12.1369 2.59099 7.86307 5.22703 5.22703ZM13.7123 6.28769C11.6621 4.23744 8.33794 4.23744 6.28769 6.28769C4.23744 8.33795 4.23744 11.6621 6.28769 13.7123C8.33794 15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 13.7123 13.7123C15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 8.33795 13.7123 6.28769Z"></path></svg></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Tell me how to achieve the correct display of search items (as in the 2nd screenshot) (in width). In this case, it is necessary that the text entered in the input field does not fit on the magnifying glass.

ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast contentballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast contentballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content ballast content

Comment: Use `flexbox` to achieve it

Comment: @AbinThaha I used flex, see more carefully.

Comment: remove 'flex: 35px' from #SearchButtondiv

Answer (score 0):

Here I am using a custom css styling without `flexbox`, instead using `position: absolute`. Check this.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#input {
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  padding-right: 30px;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

#btn {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/very-basic-2-android-l-lollipop-icon-pack/24/search-512.png');
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <input type='text' id='input' placeholder="Search" />
  <button id="btn"></button>
</div>
```

EDIT

Fixed the issue text overflowing the search icon

EDIT-2

Made the search icon as a button instead of the pseudo element

Comment: @AbinThaba the text entered in the input field fits over the button with a magnifying glass.

Comment: Ok, needs to give a padding-right. and that would solve it

Answer (score 0):

In `#SearchButtondiv` get rid of `flex: 35px`. That's a wrong value. And uncomment `justify-content: flex-end`. Also get rid of the same property in `#SearchBlock`. It's unnecessary there

```css
.crossline, .bottompart {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 33%;*/
}

.crosslineright {
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 40px;*/
    /*margin-left: 20px;*/
    /*margin-right: 20px;*/
    /*align: right;*/
    text-align: right;
}

.close {
        margin-top: -14px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
}

.dropdownwindowright {
    width: 75%;
}

.CatalogMenuSearch #SearchBlock {
    /*border-bottom: 1px solid orange;*/
}

#SearchBlock {
    padding-top: 5px;
    /*padding-left: 25px;*/
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 50px;
    /*padding-right: 50px;*/
    display: flex;
    height: 35px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#SearchInput {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    flex: 1;
}

#SearchButtondiv {
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

#SearchButton button svg{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindowright">
                    <div class="crosslineright">
                        <div class="close">&times;</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
                        <div id="SearchBlock">
                                <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по товарам" id="SearchInput">
                            <div id="SearchButtondiv">
                                <button id="SearchButton"><svg class=" Icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.22703 5.22703C7.86307 2.591 12.1369 2.591 14.773 5.22703C17.2298 7.68382 17.3968 11.5632 15.2742 14.2135L19.0607 18L18 19.0607L14.2135 15.2742C11.5632 17.3968 7.68381 17.2298 5.22703 14.773C2.59099 12.1369 2.59099 7.86307 5.22703 5.22703ZM13.7123 6.28769C11.6621 4.23744 8.33794 4.23744 6.28769 6.28769C4.23744 8.33795 4.23744 11.6621 6.28769 13.7123C8.33794 15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 13.7123 13.7123C15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 8.33795 13.7123 6.28769Z"></path></svg></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
                    </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: And how to set the numerical value of the width for `#SearchButtondiv`?

Comment: You can do that with a regular `width: 35px`

Comment: How do you make the input field fill the full width in front of the magnifying glass button (as in the 2nd screenshot)?

Comment: @megafrontprogrammer You were giving `width` to your  `#SearchInputdiv`. But you also needed to give it to the actual `<input>` element inside that div. Although, I feel it's a little unnecessary to wrap the input field inside a div. I've gotten rid of `#SearchInputdiv` and applied its styling to `#SearchInput`. You can look at the snippet now. It's been edited